# display message in the next / split or a new Line

Tags: java

the below Java code displays the error message in almost one single line

```
addErrorMessage("Легенды делают нас мудрей. Мы чувствуем пульс единой вселенной. по-моему именно эти слова из песни отражают смысл");
```

Current Out put is like

```
Легенды делают нас мудрей. Мы чувствуем пульс единой вселенной. по-моему именно эти слова из песни 
отражают смысл
```

How to add break the line in the addErrorMessage?
so that the Out put would appear some thing like the below

```
Легенды делают нас мудрей. Мы чувствуем пульс единой вселенной. 
по-моему именно эти слова из песни отражают смысл
```

Answer (score 1):

add \n which is the line break character
so:

```
addErrorMessage("Легенды делают нас мудрей. Мы чувствуем пульс единой вселенной. \nпо-моему именно эти слова из песни отражают смысл");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about `addErrorMessage`, but I would try adding `\n` in your string where you want the line break...

Ex..

```java
addErrorMessage("Легенды делают нас мудрей. Мы чувствуем пульс единой вселенной." + 
"\n" + "по-моему именно эти слова из песни отражают смысл");
```